# Flutter iOS: How to expose "Look Up" toolbarOptions in SelectableText?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm developing an app in Flutter for iOS where the user can easily look-up a word using the built-in dictionaries.

I used `SelectableText` for text so that user could select a word and that toolbar options for the selected text could be displayed. Among the `ToolbarOptions` of `SelectableText` I see `copy`, `cut`, `paste` and `selectAll` but not `lookUp` nor `share`.

I didn't try yet, but I know that `share` is available through a flutter package called "share". How do I add a `lookUp` to the `SelectableText`'s toolbar menu? Is there any package that I do not aware of or I should dive into native for this?

My current code:

```dart
SelectableText(
  this.deck[index % this.deck.length].front,
  style: kCardTextStyle,
  toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true, /* share: ??? */))
```

Comment: as of today, this is not yet supported by flutter. Here's the GitHub issue to check for updates https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82907